# I am trying to create multiple loops but if one loop returns null it doesn't run the rest of the loop. How do I get around this?

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have multiple for loops in one code, as I am trying to collect data based off identifier "Y". There are some sheets that do not have identifier "Y" and those sheets always cause my script to stop running as the error cannot find the length in that specific for loop since there is none.

How do I get around this? I've tried if/else in everywhere I think would work and it's not working.

I've tried if/else statements and breaks but I must not be putting them in the right spot.

```
var VDSLr = VDSL.getRange('A:AS'); 
var VDSLraw = VDSLr.getValues(); 
var VDSLdata = []
for (var i = 0; i< VDSLraw.length ; i++){ 
    if (VDSLraw[i][44] == "Y")
    {
        VDSLdata.push(VDSLraw[i]) 
    }
    Pull.getRange(Pull.getLastRow()+1,1, VDSLdata.length, 
    VDSLdata[0].length).setValues(VDSLdata);
}

var ITr = IT.getRange('A:AS'); 
var ITrawdata = ITr.getValues(); 
var ITd= []
for (var i = 0; i< ITrawdata.length ; i++){
    if(ITrawdata[i][44] == "Y")
    {
        ITd.push(ITrawdata[i])
    }
    Pull.getRange(Pull.getLastRow()+1,1, ITd.length, 
    ITd[0].length).setValues(ITd);
}


 **Edit: it won't let me post a picture of my error yet. Here's a few 
examples though:
Error (1):** 

var VDSLr = VDSL.getRange('A:AS'); 
var VDSLraw = VDSLr.getValues(); 
var VDSLdata = []
for (var i = 0; i< VDSLraw.length ; i++){ 
  if (VDSLraw[i][44] != "Y")**continue**;
  if (VDSLraw[i][44] == "Y");

{
VDSLdata.push(VDSLraw[i]) 
}
}
Pull.getRange(Pull.getLastRow()+1,1, VDSLdata.length, 
VDSLdata[0].length).setValues(VDSLdata);

var ITr = IT.getRange('A:AS'); 
var ITrawdata = ITr.getValues(); 
var ITd= []
for (var i = 0; i< ITrawdata.length ; i++){ 
  if (ITrawdata[i][44] != "Y")continue;
  if (ITrawdata[i][44] == "Y")
   {
   ITd.push(ITrawdata[i])
   }
}
Pull.getRange(Pull.getLastRow()+1,1, ITd.length, 
ITd[0].length).setValues(ITd);
```

So if I put a continue here, it won't read the length. Error code is "Cannot read property "length" from undefined. Which I know is correct. This is what I'm trying to bypass. "VDSL" is a sheet that normally does not have what I am looking for. But since it won't find the length it won't continue to sheet "IT."

I have also moved around the continues to different spots, and even a break (in the same spot as continue) but my combinations seem to provide a never ending loop of the same info.

The other attempt is with if else statements. When I use those I get a synthax error. On this error(2) I've tried:

```
  if (VDSLraw[i][44] == "Y")
  {//code here}
  else if (VDSLraw[i][44] != "Y"){break};
```

I feel like I'm making this more complicated than it is, should be a simple if/then statement but since I have to pull the data and compile it to one sheet the for loop is the best way to go. Just can't figure out the last piece. I could do them separately but that's my last resort. There's 12 sheets, so clicking 12 scripts each time I need to do this doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: Can you post the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Please provide [mcve];

Comment: What if you try [checking the values or printing](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger) it before entering any `for` loops, so that you will be able to identify if that is the correct value you are expecting?

Comment: I have added more, it would not let me paste pictures (as I am new.) I have posted the values and the values that I get from a working For loop is exactly what I need.

Comment: I was able to figure out what I needed, I needed to write my output this way: if(Otherdata.length != 0){Pull.getRange(Pull.getLastRow()+1,1, Otherdata.length, Otherdata[0].length).setValues(Otherdata)}; is now working. What do I do with the question? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

as soon as you provided limited information about your data I made some assumptions, I hope it matches your needs.

```
function getY_Data(){
  // get the current Spreadsheet;
  var currentSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // get all tabs on the file, so you wont need to keep track of how many tabs you have
  var tabsArray = currentSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  var resultsSheet = currentSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("results");
  var currentSheetValues;
  var collected_Y_Rows = []; 

  // iterate over all tabs
  tabsArray.forEach(function(tabObject,index){
    // skip the results tab
    if(tabObject.getName() === "results"){ continue; }
    // set the current sheet data to currentSheetValues variable
    currentSheetValues = tabsArray[0].getDataRange().getValues();

    // Im considering that all your sheets has the same row size
    currentSheetValues.forEach(function(row,index){
      if(row[44] == "Y"){
        collected_Y_Rows.push(row);
      }
    });
  });

  // if it hasnt find any row with "Y" it won't clear the "results" tab or try do add empty data to the "results" sheet
  if(collected_Y_Rows.length === 0){
    return;
  }
  // clear the current values and formats
  resultsSheet.clear();

  // append new data starting on row 1 and col 2;
  // Im considering that all your sheets has the same row size;
  // if the sheets tabs has different sizes of data (columns) it will throw an error because when using the range.setValues(collected_Y_Rows),
  // all rows on "collected_Y_Rows" mas have the same size;
  resultsSheet.getRange(1, 1, collected_Y_Rows.length, collected_Y_Rows[0].length).setValues(collected_Y_Rows);
}
```